# Linear regression in Python blows up gradients for larger values of x in y=mx+c

Tags: python, machine-learning, linear-regression

Here is my python code which implements gradient descent. It works perfectly if the values of x in y=mx+c are small enough (eg: 0-1 in this code).
If I change from `x = np.random.rand(1,500)` to `x = np.random.rand(1,500)*100`, the gradients (dlw and dlc) blow up and I get nan values after a couple of iterations for them (and hence weight w and bias c also is nan). What is wrong here?

```
class LinearRegression:
 def __init__(self,lr=0.01,iter=2000):
    self.lr = lr
    self.iter = iter

 def gradient_descent(self,y,x):
    for i in range(self.iter):
        yhat = np.dot(self.w.T,x) + self.c
        dlw = (2/self.m)*np.dot(x, (yhat-y).T)
        dlc = (2/self.m)*np.sum(yhat-y)
        self.w = self.w - self.lr*dlw
        self.c = self.c - self.lr*dlc

 def run(self, y, x):
    self.m = x.shape[1]
    self.n = x.shape[0]
    self.w = np.zeros((self.n,1))
    self.c = 0
    self.gradient_descent(y,x)
    return self.w, self.c


def main():
    x = np.random.rand(1,500) #nxm (n = no of features, m = no of examples)
    print (x.shape)
    y = 5*x + 3 +(np.random.randn(1,500)*0.1)

    algorithm = LinearRegression()
    w,c = algorithm.run(y,x)
    print (w,c)

 if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: No, 2/self.m seems to be right.
Loss L = 1/m * sum((yhat-y)^2)
Hence the gradients have the term 2/self.m

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nothing is "wrong", gradient descent **does not converge** even for linear regression case unless the learning rate is small enough. By rescaling your data you are effectively rescaling your learning rate too.

As an exemplary mathematical analysis of the phenomenon:
[https://www.stat.cmu.edu/~ryantibs/convexopt-F13/scribes/lec6.pdf](https://www.stat.cmu.edu/%7Eryantibs/convexopt-F13/scribes/lec6.pdf)

Comment: That was the problem. Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

If you got following error on updating `x = np.random.rand(1,500)*100` your main() had a few typos.

> RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in subtract self.w = self.w
>
> - self.lr*dlw [[nan]] nan

I just change a few e.g adding a bracket, reference using variable. Converge  10m, 10000m for 2.9999999999999996.

Updating W & C will trigger **double_scalars overflow**, if your learning_rate is too large(0.1 >) you need to review those two lines of code [Edited].

```
def main():
    # n = features, m = training examples
    x = np.random.randn(10,10000) 
    print(x.shape)
    y = (5 * x ) + 3 + (x * 0.1)
    algorithm = LinearRegression()
    w, c = algorithm.run(y, x)
    print(w, c)
```

[image: Result 10x10000]

Comment: The learning rate seems to be a problem. And thanks for changing the main function. Although this one had a small issue causing w be of nxn dimension, instead of nx1. But nothing major. Thanks!

Comment: This one from 2015 is simply and easy to follow http://www.wildml.com/2015/09/implementing-a-neural-network-from-scratch/